# Ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso will not boot

Tags: boot, dvd, windows-xp, burning

I have an old XP laptop that I want to refresh by using Linux.
Downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso and burnt onto DVD as an image, not just copied the iso file.  Changed the boot order to boot from DVD first. The machine tries to read the DVD for a while, but gave up and bootes Windows XP from the HDD.

I checked the MD5 and it's correct.

The DVD is not readable in Windows Xp - should it be?
I have tried 2 different DVD burners, CDburnerXp and InfraRecorder, each time choosing to burn image.  I have tried booting both on a Dell Dimension desktop and a Toshiba Equium laptop. The same result each time.  Cannot try USB as the machines do not support USB boot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the DVD should be readable in Windows. It should contain several files and folders. You should check the CD/DVD in an other computer. If it can not be opened there as well, need to create an other one. If you can read the disk on the other computer you might have a technical problem with the CD/DVD drive.